# Node ffmpeg child_process stops but still alive

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process

I have an Node App that starts multiple instances of ffmpeg through child_process, each ffmpeg transcodes a live stream from a camera.

The problem is that after 5~10 min the ffmpeg process just stops doing the transcoding, the process is still alive since I can see it on the tasks manager, but it justs stops doing the transcoding.

Now if I send the output of ffmpeg to the Node.js console log, that actually keeps the transcoding alive.

Any Ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the stdout or stderr buffers are filling up and the code blocks until they are read.
The solution is to redirect them to the parent, write them to a file, pipe them somewhere else, or ignore them (pipe them to `/dev/null`).

The simplist way, if you don't need the output, is to spawn with:

```
spawn('prg', [], { stdio: 'ignore' });
```

This is documented in the [spawn documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Comment: Just a note for others that if you DO need the `stdout`, but don't consume `stderr`, it will STILL BREAK!  You need to explicitly map `stderr` to `ignore`.